# node.js http "value" required in setHeader("Content-Type", value)?

Tags: node.js

i get file extname, but is undefined and throw the error is:

```
"value" required in setHeader("Content-Type", value)
```

getFileType.js

```
const path = require('path')

const mimeType = {
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css",
    "png": "image/png",
    "jpg": "image/jpg",
    "gif": "image/gif",
    "html": "text/html"
}

module.exports = (filePath) => {
    let extFileName = path.extname(filePath)
        .split('.')
        .pop()
        .toLowerCase()

    if (!extFileName) {
        extFileName = filePath
    }

    return mimeType[extFileName] || mimeType['txt']
}
```

then i call the mimeType

```
const mimeType = require('./getFileType')

if (stats.isFile()) {
    const fileType = mimeType(filePath)

    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType)
    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res)
}
```

when i refresh browser, the cmd console: "value" required in setHeader("Content-Type", value)?

when i debugger `const fileType = mimeType(filePath)` get 'undefined'

and browser error: E:\forld\README.md is not a directory or file

i'm not understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are giving a file which has an extension apart from the ones you have in the `mimeType` object. If that's the case, you are returning a default value `mimeType['txt']` but there is no `txt` key in the `mimeType` object. So add the `txt` key to your `mimeType` object.

```
const mimeType = {
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css",
    "png": "image/png",
    "jpg": "image/jpg",
    "gif": "image/gif",
    "html": "text/html",
    "txt": "application/text"
}
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! :)